# Completeness of $L^1$ space

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I'm studying this proof:

[https://www.math.utah.edu/~savin/L2_5210.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Esavin/L2_5210.pdf)

but I can't understand the step when he says: *Hence, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, there exists an integrable function $\phi$,  such  that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(x)  =\phi(x)$  for  almost all $x$.*

The monotone convergence theorem that I have studied does not have the existence of the limit function $\phi$ in the thesis, but in the hypothesis. In fact, why the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(x)$ could not be infinite on a non-zero measure set?

Comment: I believe this is covered since $\sum_{i}f_i$ is assumed to be absolutely convergent?

Comment: I think the existence part follows directly (without the MCT), but proving that this limit is also *integrable* requires the MCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can understand this step :

1. $\varphi := \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \varphi_n$ exists since $(\varphi_n)$ is an increasing sequence of function. At this step, we still don't know that $\varphi$ is integrable.
2. By Monotone Convergence Theorem, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int \varphi_n = \int  \varphi$$
3. Because you have $\displaystyle{\int \varphi_n \leq \sum ||f_i||}$ for every $n$, then you deduce from 2. that $$\int  \varphi \leq \sum ||f_i||  < \infty$$

so $\varphi$ is integrable and you are done.

Comment: This method is clear if the monotone convergence theorem still holds for “extended” functions. That is, functions that could assume $+\infty$ as a value. Is it really this the case? Can one recycle the proof of the MCT also for this type of functions, without variations?

Comment: @Nameless Yes. In Lebesgue theory, functions are generally allowed to take $\infty$ as a value, and all the main theorems remain true. You can check the proof of MCT to see that it has no influence.